# $\{a_n\} \in \mathcal{l}^2$, $\epsilon$ given, could we find $N$ such that for $i > N$, $a_i < \epsilon$ and for $a_{i^2}<\frac{\epsilon}{i}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose, $\{a_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N} \in \mathcal{l}^2$, which means, $\sum_{n\in \Bbb N}{a_n}^2 < +\infty$. given any $\epsilon$, could we find $N$  such that for any $i > N$, $a_i < \epsilon$ and for $a_{i^2}<\frac{\epsilon}{i}$?

If not, is there a $p$ such that given any $\epsilon$, we could find $N$  such that for any $i > N$, $a_i < \epsilon$ and for $a_{i^p}<\frac{\epsilon}{i}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition $a_i<\varepsilon$ for $i$ large enough is not a problem. But the second one is: take 
$$a_{2^j}:=\frac 1j$$
and $a_k=0$ if $k$ is not of the form $2^j$ for some $j$.

If $i^p=2^j$, (for example $i=2^l$ and $j=pl$), then $ia_{i^p}= \frac{2^{j/p}}j,$
and this doesn't goes to $0$.